# Git status out of memory

Tags: git, sourcetree

I have a fairly large repository with large files in it.
I was working on my local branch for a few days and decided to push today. Unfortunately, "git status" returns an out of memory error.
I tried changing a few memory allocation sizes in the config files without luck. What am I doing wrong ? Something I can do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add part by part when you push.

Like so :

**Part one**

```
git add folder-one/*
git commit -m 'Message'
git push
```

**Part two**

```
git add folder-two/*
git commit -m 'Message'
git push
```

Comment: This worked ! Somehow..
Still don't know why git status was failing but thanks a lot for the fix !